# Can I disable Google Chrome Autofill ONLY for localhost?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm a developer and it's VERY annoying having Chrome suggest all my personal address information in forms one web sites I'm developing on running on my local machine.  Is disabling Autofill on localhost, or a domain, or an IP address possible?  I'm not seeing anything in the advanced settings.

Comment: Although "as a developer", don't you want the same experience on your local test server as you would on the live site?

Comment: If I want to test browser specific stuff like Autofill, I would do it against a test server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently answered another question with the same requirement of customizing features of Chrome (and also inspired from [@Paul](https://superuser.com/questions/523877/can-i-disable-google-chrome-autofill-only-for-localhost/528254#528254)).

> NOTE: This solution allows you to block a specific IP address or list
>   of IPs, without having to load **any additional library** and **no
>   additional scripts** in your project. Fact often you may have blocked
>   all Javascript features, but the control "noautofill" follow operating,
>   avoiding collisions with other libraries, allowing also you have a real
>   recognition of the consumption charge and rendering time, and this can
>   translate into savings of time debugging day to day, on different web
>   projects.

Create a Chrome extension that uses the "match filter host" of the Chrome API, and filter your custom `IP host` or `namehost`. Then set the attribute `autocomplete` to `off`  for all "input" and "form" tags.

We proceed with these steps:

- Create a new folder named ex. **noautofill**
- Create into our new folder, a new file named ***manifest.json*** and add this code inside:

```
{
  "name": "No Autofill",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "No Autofill.",  
  "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "exclude_globs": [  ],
      "include_globs": [ "*" ],  
      "js": [ "script.js" ],      
      "matches": [   
                   "http://192.168.1.100/",
                   "http://127.0.0.1/",
                   "http://10.0.1.100/",
                   "http://localhost/",
                   "http://wp.local/",
                   "http://192.168.1.100/*",
                   "http://127.0.0.1/*",
                   "http://10.0.1.100/*",
                   "http://localhost/*",
                   "http://wp.local/*"                   
                    ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/", "https://*/*", "http://*/*", "contextMenus" ]

}
```

- In our new folder, create a new file named ***script.js*** and add this code inside:

```
(function(){    
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({
        autofill:'off'
    },function(){       
        var inputnodes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');    
        for(var i=0;i<inputnodes.length;i++){       
            inputnodes[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
        }       
        var formnodes = document.getElementsByTagName("form");    
        for(var i=0;i<formnodes.length;i++){                    
            formnodes[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
        }       
  });
})();
```

- We  go to Chrome's menu » Settings » Extensions
- Now we click the button "Load unpacked extensions"
- Finally we mark our folder and click on the open button.

This is the result:

[image: noautofill]

This system is very simple, and you can customize the file *script.js* with your own control code. In the future you may add other scripts, CSS, configuration pages, etc. Remember that every time you will make changes in the file *script.js* you should reload the plugin with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

Also you can get a [more detiled guide about how to create Chrome extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html).

Comment: Please don't overdo it with the formatting. Remember, sometimes less is more. I edited your post to remove the bold, italics and quotes that are not needed.

Comment: No problem, just a tip for the future :)

Comment: I like this solution the most, thank you!  Not a big fan of having to manage multiple profiles, which would work, just not the solution I'm looking for.  This allows things to be more streamlined for me.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Nice solution! I think you may have missed a wildcard on the second http://10.0.1.100/ though?

Comment: wow yes! that watchful eyes :)

Answer (score 10):

*The other answers regarding using a second profile or installing a second version of Chrome should work fine. I'm taking a different angle only to provide another option, not because I think this is a better way of doing it.*

---

As you are developing a website locally, simply include the jQuery library and a jQuery script with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input").attr("autocomplete","off");
});
```

This turns auto-fill off for all inputs on the webpage. Used in conjunction with a server-side include file (in the head) means it would be very easy to add this during testing and remove it for production for an entire website.

Comment: 1+ You have inspired me, for my second solution.

Comment: Works great, I would add that you could put this code in a server side if statement that checks a setting to tell what enivornment the website is running on. In my case for MVC mine looks like this `@if (Web.Core.Common.Settings.Environment == Web.Core.Common.Environments.Local)
            {
                @Html.Raw("$(':input').attr('autocomplete','off');");
            }`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Google Chrome does not have a per-site filtering option for auto-fill.

One alternative is to use the [Lastpass Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd?hl=en), where you can decide which field to be remembered on a per-site basis.

The other alternative is by creating a new user profile **Chrome settings -> Users -> Add new user** or installing different versions of chrome (Chrome Stable / Beta / Dev, [Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs), or [Chromium](http://download-chromium.appspot.com/)).

Answer (score 2):

One solution (for test purposes) would be to [Add new user profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) without Autofill.

Use this profile while testing to avoid Autofill.

Comment: It's not the nicest solution - you still want to be using the internet as normal on all the otherwebsites.

Answer (score 1):

Could achieve their purpose with [**Autofill**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/autofill?hl=en-US) extension.

I think it has all the features you are looking for.

[image: autofill]

Answer (score 0):

The [property autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) on input elements can be disabled to avoid autofilling. Grabbing [all the input elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and setting this property can be done with native javascript code. If you just need it on the fly, you can open up the dev-tools and open up the console tab, and run this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach((el) => {
  el.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

Or if you never want autofill on this specific site, you could include something like this in your development bundle, which disables all fields when the [page is fully loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  disableAutofill();
});

function disableAutofill() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach((el) => {
    el.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).